# What to do if I upgarde to the latest version and the only available kernel does not work?

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kernel

So I have a 2005 one-core Acer, was great at the time but old now. Ubuntu has kept this thing moving forward working very well, however the latest two versions have been heavy on it. Most importantly the last one I downloaded worked relatively fine but as I installed updates and kernels those didn't work.

Example:
Kernel 3.2 works fine but the newer 3.5 don't even load up. My question is i I download the latest release and it gets rid of 3.2 and the new one doesn't load up how would I manage getting an old kernel up on the GRUB or put in an older version of Ubuntu.

Thank you and sorry for being so novice at this.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you manually deleted the old kernel, you will still have these on your machine.

Hold down the Shift key as you boot up and it will take you to the Grub screen. From here, you can choose which version of the kernel to boot into.

If you really don't need the newer ones you can find which kernel you're currently using by going to the terminal and running

```
uname -r
```

to see which kernel you're using. Then run

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

and note the kernel versions you don't need anymore (anything starting 3.5 I guess but if the kernel you're running works fine, you can get read of all the others). Then you can run

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.5.x-xx-generic
```

That should free up some disk space for you too

Comment: Awesome. This sounds good I can get rid of those that don't work and allow me to load automatically without going down the list. But my concern is that every time I load a new ubuntu upgrade a new kernel comes with it. Considering 3.5 doesnt work I'm worried that what comes with a new one won't either, and usually when I upgrade it gets rid of my available kernels on the grub. Through this process that you gave me if I had to go into safe mode and get 3.2 is that a possibility?

Comment: When you run your update, you should be able to see if a new kernel has been installed. It requires a restart before your new kernel takes effect, so running your safe 3.2.xx kernel, before you restart your machine you can apt-get purge the new kernel, to stop it from loading automatically - it can't delete the kernel you're using until it shifts to the new one, so that should solve the problem. Hope this helps :)