# multiple versions of ubuntu on laptop

Tags: 12.04

I got laptop from friend who tried to install 13.04 and don't know the status. Would never reboot. I installed 11 and then upgraded to 12.04. When I reboot it wont' boot but hard reboot brings up screen with 3 options: Ubuntu 3.8.0.19, 3.8.0.19(recovery mode), previous Linux Versions. If I select 3.8.0.19 it will stall OS come up. Hard boot again and If I select 3.8.0.19(recovery mode)then it will partially boot and throw messages but OS won't come up. I had reboot again and select previous versions then I get further choices 3.2.0-48-generic-pae, 3.2.0-48-generic-pae(recovery mode), 3.2.0-48-generic, 3.2.0-48-generic (recovery mode), 3.2.0-32-generic-pae,  3.2.0-32-generic-pae(recovery mode). I selected 3.2.0-48-generic-pae then I see 12.04LTS will come up. I want to just keep 12.04, without selecting every time from all these versions/options. Can you please tell me what to do?

Comment: Also only hard boot works, soft reboot from OS won't bring up the boot screen. If I do soft shutdown and start it won't reboot, but second hard reboot works. I want to be able to soft reboot from OS and get to 12.04 version without all the options/selection I have to go through. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

@Bernie B 's answer is a thorough option, but the details in my reply to this question: [What to do if I upgarde to the latest version and the only available kernel does not work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308441/what-to-do-if-i-upgarde-to-the-latest-version-and-the-only-available-kernel-does/308452#308452) would also work for you, without the need for a backup or data loss.

If when you installed 11.xx you used the whole disk, and then did a release upgrade to 12.04, the whole disk is already formatted correctly for you and the only issue is the kernel you're trying to run.

Once you have the working kernel (3.2.0-48) then you can delete the rest of them that come up with the **dpkg --list | grep linux-image** command - as per my other post - using apt-get (again, the code for this is in the answer on the other thread).

That way, when you boot up your machine it will have to load the older kernel as there wont be a non-working one to boot from